# Regularity for Laplacian operator on non-compact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete non-compact Riemannian manifold . 
Thanks to @EveryLT, we know that the Poisson equation 
$$\Delta u=f,$$
is solvable 
for some $f\in L^2_k(M)$.

**Q** Suppose that $(M,g)$ is of bounded geometry, can we say that $u\in L^2_{k+2}$.

Comment: It is obviously false, $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f=0$... you have to consider the Kernel of the Laplacian, as in  1.16 of Bartnik paper : http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math646/bartnik.mass.pdf